# Elasticsearch: 2-node cluster with failover

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using **Elasticsearch 1.5.2** and trying to setup a 2-node cluster. These 2 nodes are primarily for failover strategy (if any one node goes down, the other one is still there to handle requests), I don't need to divide primary shards or something like that, (total data is no more than 500mb on hard-disk).

Everything goes well, until **Split Brains** thing kicks in. Now, since I don't have much data, I don't feel any requirement of 3 nodes. And I want to have failover mechanism too. Which means, `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` cannot be more than `1`.

Now, I have two questions:

1. Is there any configuration possible, which could overcome **2 master nodes** or **Split Brains** problem?
2. If not, what all other options do I have to make it work? Like, keeping both in different clusters (one online, other one offline) and updating offline with online, time to time, for the time when online cluster goes down. Or, do I have to go for 3-node cluster?

I am going on production environment. Please help.

Comment: A two node cluster with `discovery.zen.minimum_master_node: 1` **will not** prevent split-brains.  The answer to your question 1. is "No". The answer for question 2. is "whatever you find more appropriate". Meaning go with 3 nodes cluster OR (depending if it's easy or not) go with two clusters. My suggestion: add a third node.

Comment: Thanks for your straight reply. At least, you havn't given the universal answer of all elasticsearch questions i.e. **It depends**. Now I am thinking there is one more way. I can make any 1 of the 2 nodes as master, and the other one as **data-only** node. If my master node goes down, I can make my **data-only** node as master. But still, there will be some downtime. Given, that I can make my data-only node master on the fly.

Comment: This sounds hacky... and seems to be the same as having two clusters: the cluster will always be `yellow` (no replicas assigned) and you still need to "switch". What kind of machines are these? And how heavy the indexing/searching is on the cluster?

Comment: Two machines (VMWare driven), having 4 cores, 8gb RAM and CentOS. We are firing 7-8 queries (1 `_search` and other `_count`) per search. Indexing op won't be very frequent (until we sync existing indices from DB through `_bulk` API), but searching is going to be quite frequent. Have a look at this: http://test.sapvirtualevents.com/teched/en/search/mark

Comment: So, this won't be that low in searches and the hardware seems to be enough... Depending on how many indices you have, I'd try (to be on the safe side here) 3 primary shards, 1 replica on **3 nodes**. In this way, you have the power to serve requests and, also, you can rest assured regarding split-brains.